# How do I create a colour theme in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vs-color-theme-editor

The Visual Studio Code website says in this link: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/color-theme#create-a-new-color-theme that I'm to "Use VS Code's Yeoman extension generator to generate a new theme extension." then it shows me what I'm to type in:

```
npm install -g yo generator-code
yo code
```

The problem is, after typing it into the terminal, I get this message:

```
npm : The term 'npm' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or 
if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

Have I typed it into the wrong place, or have I made a mistake somewhere else?

I followed the previous step and it seemed to be working so I'm confused as to where I went wrong. Thank you for helping.

Comment: Do you have ```node.js``` added to ```PATH``` in your environment variables?

Comment: The VS-color-theme tag is for Visual Studio IDE I believe, not VS Code

Comment: Also, this is a problem with using NPM, not with creating a VSCode theme. You need to first get NPM & Node.js to work, only then should you install and use 3rd party Yeoman CLI built tools from NPM.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure to add `node.js` path to `PATH` environmental variable.

Open `cmd` as Administrator and type

```
setx /M path "%path%;C:\path_to_node.js"
```

Usual, Node.js is found at `C`

Anyway, it should be already added on `PATH` upon installation of Node.JS.

Comment: None of this is required to use `YEOMAN` built Command-line Interfaces. It also shouldn't be required for node, unless it is maybe specific to a platform I haven't used like MacOS (which there is good reason why I don't use it). In general, this question isn't platform-specific, and shouldn't be answered as such. He/She should be able to simple install node, and NPM via standard Node Installation tools. I like to use NVM personally. Go here if you haven't already, and download & install node: https://nodejs.org/en/download/